# cancelRequests(context, true) in Asynchronous Http Client is not working

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-async-http

I need to start and stop the Http request based on AsychronousHttpClient library. i can able to get start the request and getting data from the server but i cannot able to stop the request? Can Anyone suggest any ideas.  This is my sample code.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Context context;
public  NSUCDownload downloadDishes;
public  ByteArrayEntity entity;
public  String jsonData;


Button send,cancel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this;

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() 
                { 
                    PostMethod();
                }


            }); t1.start();             
        }
    });
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        // cancel code

            Client.cancelAllRequests(context);
        }
    });

}
void PostMethod()
{

    JSONObject objRootNode = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray aryChildNodes = new JSONArray();
    aryChildNodes.put("some data" );// here parameter for POST data


    try {
        objRootNode.put("lstDishKeys_in", aryChildNodes);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Json Request for = "+objRootNode.toString());
    String postString = objRootNode.toString();
    downloadDishes = new NSUCDownload("http:// link which contains value for the Post data",postString,this);
    entity = downloadDishes.start();
    try {
        if(entity!=null)
        {
            jsonData = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(" Json Data="+jsonData);// here i get final data
        }
        else
            jsonData=null;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

This is Download Class which is interact with Client class

```
public class NSUCDownload {

Context context;
public String url;
public GetJsonData objGetJsonData;
int methodtype = 1;
String postData = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;
ByteArrayEntity responseEntity=null;

Client clientRequest=new Client();


public NSUCDownload(String url, String in_postData, MainActivity context) {
    this.url = url;
    this.postData = in_postData;
    this.methodtype = 2;
    this.context=context;
}

public ByteArrayEntity start()
{
    objGetJsonData = new GetJsonData();
    try {
        objGetJsonData.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return objGetJsonData.getData();
}


public class GetJsonData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,HttpEntity>
{

    public ByteArrayEntity getData()
    {
        return responseEntity;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HttpEntity result) {
        System.out.println("On_Post_Execute_Invoked");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpEntity doInBackground(Void...none) {
        try {
            if (methodtype == POST) {
                if (postData != null) {
                    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(postData);  
                    Client.post(context,url,entity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int statusCode,org.apache.http.Header[] headers,byte[] responseBody) {

                            responseEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(responseBody);
                            System.out.println(" Success ="+responseBody);


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int statusCode,org.apache.http.Header[] headers,byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                            System.out.println( "Failure");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseEntity;

    }
}
```

}

Finally this is my Client Class:

```
public class Client {
static AsyncHttpClient asyncClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
 static AsyncHttpClient syncClient = new SyncHttpClient();
 static AsyncHttpClient clientReq;

public static void post(Context context, String url, StringEntity entity,String string, AsyncHttpResponseHandler asyncHttpResponseHandler) {
    clientReq=getClient();
    clientReq.post(context, url, entity, "application/json", asyncHttpResponseHandler );
    System.out.println("Context=="+context);

}

private static AsyncHttpClient getClient()
{
    // Return the synchronous HTTP client when the thread is not prepared
    if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
    {
        System.out.println(" Getting SyncHttpClient Object");
        return syncClient;
    }
    System.out.println(" Getting AsyncHttpClient Object");

    return asyncClient;
}
```

/*I used this method but still it does not cancel the request. */

```
public static void cancelAllRequests(Context context)
{
    clientReq.cancelRequests(context, true);
    //clientReq.cancelAllRequests(true);

    System.out.println("CancledRequest ");
}
```

}

Comment: Before i use getClient(); i get error like this Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Synchronous ResponseHandler used in AsyncHttpClient. You should create your response handler in a looper thread or use SyncHttpClient instead.

Comment: Then only i add getClient() which initially returns Synchronous object only and when i try to use to call the cancelRequests like getClient().cancelRequest(context,true), then it returns Asynchronous object... i think some going wrong while create objects .. this is my dought